# Is it possible to avoid certificate warnings in Apache for alternate SSL host names?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache server serving a single virtual host `https://app.example.com`.

For legacy reasons the site is also known under another name `https://myapp.example.com`.

For users connecting to the legacy name, they get a browser certificate warning because obviously the certificate common name doesn't match the hostname.

Is it possible to use Apache rewrite rules to avoid this warning and have the client connect to the correct host?

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=app.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteRule ^ https://app.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Basically, no. The client will trigger the warning when it tries to negotiate HTTPS in the first communication. The only way to avoid this is to use a wildcard or SAN certificate valid for both names, or have separate valid certificates on both. The Rewrite happens _way_ late in the game, well after the warning will be triggered by the browsers.

Comment: @Colt this is what I was getting confused about. Apache will present the SSL certificate, but I was hoping the rewrite would take place first before SSL negotiation.

Comment: The SSL setup is the very first thing that happens when the client (browser) makes a request to port 443.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, no.

The client (browser) will trigger the warning when it tries to negotiate HTTPS in the first communication. The only way to avoid this is to use a wildcard or SAN certificate valid for both names, or have separate valid certificates on both.

The Rewrite happens *way* late in the game, well after the warning will be triggered by the browsers.